# python tkinter.ttk combobox down event on mouseclick

Tags: python, events, combobox, tkinter, ttk

I do not find a correct answer to my issue, despite intense research and a rather simple problem.
All I would like to do, is my comboboxes drop down when clicked on by 'Button-1'. But regardless of what I code, the combos don't behave as I wish.

following I prepared a simple code to demonstrate my problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk


def combo_events(evt):
    if int(evt.type) is 4:
        w = evt.widget
        w.event_generate('<Down>')


root = Tk()
li = ('row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3')

combo1 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(root, value=li)
combo2 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(root, value=li)

combo1.bind('<Button-1>', combo_events)
combo2.bind('<Button-1>', combo_events)

combo1.pack()
combo2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Well, if I try this code, the combos do dropdown, but not as expected. So, I tried to add a bind of the 'FocusIn' event but that rather complicates the situation and inhibits a 'FocusOut' ...

Can any1 help me to achieve my goal?

ps: I know, that the combo will drop down by clicking on the frame of the widget, but to be more precise I would like to drop it, when clicking into it.

And by the way, where do I find a rather complete list of events a combobox can trigger?

thx for effort and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `int(evt.type) is 4` instead of `int(evt.type) == 4` ?

Applying this change it works for me.

**Edit 1**

First of all, thank you for explaining to us what you really want to have. Did not expect this from your initial question.

If you want to override the editing behaviour it is time to dig a little deeper.

The widget you click into inside the combobox is an entry widget. What you can do now is to define when your event shall be fetched inside the event chain. Will apply code soon.

**Edit 2**

To get it at the first mouse click:

`w.event_generate('<Down>', when='head')`

Why? Because default of Event Generate is to append the generated Event to the Event Chain (put it at its end, value = 'tail'). Changing to `when='head'` gives your desired behaviour.

Comment: For that matter, why check at all? There's only one binding, so it can only ever have a single value.

Comment: Hi, of course there is just one binding in my sample code which i cut down just to show the effect i was writing abt. in fact, there are quite many bindings in my real code.

Comment: Also, i am checking for identity since i am comparing with an int, but nevertheless of course you can check with the equality operator in the same way. Nevertheless, this change will not solve the problem. If you try and click in the combobox, it will first enable you to write into it (set Focus?) and only drop down on the second click. But what i am trying to do is, that it will do both in the same time (or if not possible, then drop down rather than enable you to write into it.

Comment: ah this makes sense, wasn't aware of that. thx for explanation. looking forward. rgds

Comment: this is just a great answer. nice and small code, works perfectly and i learned a new thing. many thanks !